# LINQ to SQL where ID not in some_list

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to make a LINQ to SQL statement which filters results where the ID is **not** in some list of integers. I realise the .contains() method cannot be used in Linq to SQL but for the purposes of explaining what I'd like to do, here's what I'd like to do:

```
nextInvention = (from inv in iContext.Inventions
                    where !historyList.Contains(inv.Id)
                    orderby inv.DateSubmitted ascending
                    select inv).First<Invention>();
```

Any idea how I might go about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`Contains` *can* be used in LINQ to SQL... it's the normal way of performing "IN" queries. I have a vague recollection that there are some restrictions, but it definitely can work. The restrictions may be around the types involved... is `historyList` a `List<T>`? It probably isn't supported for arbitrary `IEnumerable<T>`, for example.

Now, I don't know whether inverting the result works to give a "NOT IN" query, but it's at least worth trying. Have you tried the exact query from your question?

One point to note: I think the readability of your query would improve if you tried to keep one clause per line:

```
var nextInvention = (from inv in iContext.Inventions 
                     where !historyList.Contains(inv.Id)
                     orderby inv.DateSubmitted ascending
                     select inv)
                    .First();
```

Also note that in this case, the method syntax is arguably simpler:

```
var nextInvention = iContext.Inventions
                            .Where(inv => !historyList.Contains(inv.Id))
                            .OrderBy(inv => inv.DateSubmitted)
                            .First();
```

Comment: Thanks mate! Works perfectly. Also, I did have it on one clause per line, my naivete was in stackoverflow's markup ^_^ I didn't surround the code properly. Cheers anyhow :)